Philosophers’ relevance for therapy and psychology
I’m curious which philosophers are considered especially relevant for therapists and psychology work? I ask because a lot of the discussions philosophers have on a good life, the nature of consciousness and its relation to existence etc seem to overlap with therapy and psychology, and many psychologists have been influential in philosophy (for example, Karl Jaspers in existentialism, Jacques Lacan in postmodernism, Carl Jung in literary theory and religious philosophy etc.).

Wittgenstein had this therapeutic view of philosophy which is not to resolve problems but to dissolve them, and contemporary analytic philosopher John McDowell holds similar views...

Positive psychology and a number of therapeutic methods, including those used by existential therapists, directly appeals to humanism and philosophy. Existentialism had a tremendous influence on Rollo May, Carl Rogers, and R.D. Laing, a noted anti-psychologist.

Religion also overlaps therapy and psychology: many pastors, ministers and others do counseling, not only within a church setting. Many people find gardening therapeutic... Someone defined a 'hobby' as, "Something that doesn't talk back to you", yet it still is mentally healing.

Well, I don't exactly know about philosophers that are relevant for psychology and therapy in general. There are certainly intersections, like for example C.G. Jung's works, but most of them do not play a role in contemporary psychology and therapy, including the enigmatic Mr. Freud himself who is not considered a useful point of reference in psychology these days (it is rather the more scientifically sound work of his daughter Anna Freud, that, in turn, does not have much philosophical relevance). Psychology and therapy  move ever closer toward evidence-based science, hence the place for philosophy grows ever smaller.
A rather recent example of works on the relevance of philosophy in the context of psychological therapy is this thesis, which establishes an interesting view on how the works of Plessner and Buytendijk may provide a systematic base for interpreting and explaining mental disorders and help inform possible therapeutic interventions.

I can't comment because I don't have the reputation (new user).
But you should look into philosophical counseling/therapy. It's a (newer, I believe) form of therapy that is more focused on addressing problems through philosophical reasoning and dialogue. You could look into the philosophers that counselors often draw on.
